# Is this possible to limit the file size when uploading the file size in asp?

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, file-upload

In my Asp page i want to limit the file size uploaded by the client at the time of immediately choosing the file name.for example,I want to limit file size up to 2MB only.So, after user choosing the file name, i have to check the file size.If it is less than 2MB then no issue.Otherwise, i have to display the error message...

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible, although depending on the technique used for client-side checking it can generally be circumvented fairly easily.

Comment: @QuintinRobinson : thanks for your suggestion.could you please tell me the way to do that?

Comment: This article may be a help: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx

Comment: @Saravanan you can also accomplish this by calling javascript function on click of button and then checking the file size and performing your required action of showing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the maxRequestLength attribute of the httpRuntime element in the web.config as explained here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: How would you give the user a friendly validation message for this?

Comment: @IrishChieftain : I think I would start by telling the user what the size limit is and then when an attempted upload fails (it would throw a ConfigurationErrorsException) return a friendly message. I would also have a look at http://www.kavoir.com/2009/01/check-for-file-size-with-javascript-before-uploading.html and/or http://deepeshdarshan.wordpress.com/2012/06/20/how-to-validate-upload-file-size-and-file-extension-using-javascript/